# Opencart - Block adding Same product to the Cart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-module

How to block a same Product being added to the cart twice?

Ex: **Online Bookstore site has different books.** I want the customer to be able to add a book (Ex; Book name : Cricket 911) only once to the cart and want to restrict adding the same book to the cart again.

Have anyone done this kind of a development before?

Comment: Yes, you could disable the button once you've received the `success` response in the Ajax call (that adds the product to the cart)

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the code in controller **catalog/checkout/cart.php** function **add()**

You need to get the products in cart, for that you can call the funtion of system/library/cart/cart.php getProducts() by

```
$products = $this->cart->getProducts();
```

You need to check if the product that is being added to the cart exists in the **$products** by comparing **product_id**

If the product exists, you can add error to **$json['error']**. All this processing should be done before "**if (!$json) {**" in the function **add()** so that the product isn't added to the cart.

Answer (score -1):

When saving user cart information format it in this way:

```
[
    bookID: bookInfo
]
```

Then any same `bookID` will override previous selection and you will have unique keys